# `yarn run dev` creates .next folder and does not let me make changes

Tags: next.js

I am trying to run `yarn run dev` on my Next.js app but it always builds the .next directory and doesn't update the code for me to test.
It seems to be using the build folder even though I am trying to run a dev copy.
It's straight from create next app so not sure why it's doing this all of a sudden.
Even deleting .next file just recreates it on save.

Comment: _"doesn't update the code for me to test"_ - how are you trying to update the code? Next.js creating the `.next` folder is expected when running `next dev`. Changing your source code while the dev server is running should also reflect the changes in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete `react` and `react-dom` from package.json and then re-install them. Thanks